# Rounding a double to avoid round off in subsequent summation

Tags: c, floating-point, double, ieee-754

How do I implement this?

```
// round to the nearest double so that x + ref doesn't cause round off error
double round(double x, double ref) { }
```

So that

```
double x = ....;
double y = ....;

double x_new = round(x, y);
return x_new + y; // NO ROUND OFF!
```

In other terms (y + x_new) - x_new is strictly equal to y

Comment: This is not generally possible in the way you want. The text “to the nearest double” suggests you want to return an `x_new` near `x`. However, if `x` is larger than `y`, then any addition to `y` of some number near `x` will force some of the low bits of `y` out of the sum. E.g., suppose `x` is 2**64 and `y` is 1. The nearest `double` (using IEEE-754 64-bit binary) that satisfies the requirement is 2**53-1, and that is not at all near 2**64.

Comment: @eric , that's correct. Let's assume that x normalized exponent (as returned by frexp) is smaller or equal to y/ref normalized exponent

Comment: I changed the title because “double rounding” already has a specific meaning, with “double” used as an adjective.

Comment: Note that checking that `(y + x_new) - x_new == y` is not the same as checking that `x_new + y` is exact. The latter implies the former but is not necessary for it. Example: `y=1e300, x_new=1`. `(y + x_new) - x_new == 1e300 == y` but the addition `y + x_new` is not exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that `x` and `y` are both positive.

Let `S` be the double-precision sum `x + y`.

There are two cases:

- if `x` ≤ `y`, then `S - y` is exact by Sterbenz's lemma. It follows that the addition `(S - y) + y` is exact (it produces exactly `S`, which is a double-precision number). Therefore, you can pick `S - y` for `x_new`. Not only `y + x_new` is exact, but it produces the same result `S` as `y + x`.
- if `x` > `y`, then depending on the number of bits set in the significand of `y`, you may have a problem. If the last bit in the significand of `y` is set, for instance, then no number `z` in a binade after the binade of `y` can have the property that `z + y` is exact.

---

This answer is vaguely related to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17641358/139746).

Comment: 0b10000011000100100110111010010111100011010100111111100 <- 0.001 
0b10000011000100100110111010010111100011010101000000000 <- 0.001 rounded ref 1.0 @pascal solution
0b10000011000100100110111010010111100011010100000000000 <- 0.001 rounded ref 1.0 my solution
If I'm not mistake your solution is not correct (9 bits zeroed instead of 10 bits). I guess it depends on floating point rounding mode. What do you think?

Comment: @paolo_losi I was too slowly arriving to the conclusion that my solution was slightly off (great that you found an example). To be precise, I was wondering whether changing my solution to `2*y - (2*y - x)` would make it correct (still assuming 0 ≤ `x` ≤ `y`). At least now I can try it on your example, which will be a clue if not a proof yet.

Comment: @paolo_losi I have revamped my answer quite a bit. It now contains a demonstrably correct solution for the same hypotheses my previous answer wanted (0 ≤ `x` ≤ `y`). In the case where `x` is larger than `y` it may be impossible to provide a satisfactory `x_new`, for instance if the significand of `y` ends in a set bit.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution in Python that can be straightforwardly translated to C

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal


def round2(x, ref):
    x_n, x_exp     = math.frexp(x)
    ref_n, ref_exp = math.frexp(ref)
    assert x_exp <= ref_exp
    diff_exp = ref_exp - x_exp

    factor = 2. ** (53 - diff_exp)

    x_new_as_int = int(round(x_n * factor))
    x_new_as_norm_float = float(x_new_as_int) / factor
    return math.ldexp(x_new_as_norm_float, x_exp)


x = 0.001
y = 1.0

assert (y + x) - x != y

x_new = round2(x, y)

assert (y + x_new) - x_new == y

print "x:", Decimal(x)
print "x_new:", Decimal(x_new)

print "relative difference:", (x_new/x - 1.)
```

Comment: Looks like this solution relies on IEEE-754 64-bit binary.  C does not specify `double` as [IEEE-754 64-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).  Are you looking for a solution that works in C generically or not?

Comment: @chux it definitely should be C99 portable. I wasn't aware that ieee-754 64 bit != c99 double.