# Sum of fractions of 1 not exactly equally 1

Tags: matlab, floating-point, floating-accuracy, fractions

I'm creating a 3D matrix(lat,long,landuse)and trying to calculate the fraction of the landuse for each matrix cell:

One example cell could produce a vector specified by:

```
fractions=landuse/total_number_of_landuse;
```

I have to do this for multiple cells and when I do this and sum up the fractions, some are 1 and some are 1.0000.
[image: This is how it looks]
I know this is due to the floating point "problem".

I have to use these data for a C++-Modell which is checking the sum also and then throws me an error for some of the cells (those which summs up to 1.0000).

I also tried calculating these as double or single.

Any idea how I can make them sum up to 1?

Thanks, Philipp

Comment: Just round them off if they are within some tolerance of 1? [Pertinent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738)...

Comment: @gnovice if I round up the sum in matlab, that wouldnt solve the problem when the c++ programm summs up the the fractions

Comment: I meant you could do that when you check it in the C++ program.

Comment: Since the programm is some 10k lines I dont want to mess with that, since it has probably a purpose for the check.

Comment: You can't make then sum to exactly `1`, in general. You need to compare (in the C++ program) with a tolerance, maybe about `1e-15`. So instead of `x==1` you'd do something like `abs(x-1)<=1e-15`

Comment: [Not quite a duplicate, but similar and possibly helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641300/rounding-floats-so-that-they-sum-to-precisely-1/17641358#17641358)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Well, you _could_ make them add to exactly 1, by rounding each fraction to an integer multiple of `2^-53` (assuming IEEE 754 binary64 format), and then tweaking the rounded fractions as necessary to make things work, perhaps using something resembling the [largest remainder method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method). But it seems unlikely that this is the right solution to the OPs problem.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point. I agree on both accounts